# Calls to ReadFile return ERROR_WORKING_SET_QUOTA

Tags: winapi, readfile, overlapped-io

The program runs fine for a few minutes and then ReadFile starts failing with error code ERROR_WORKING_SET_QUOTA.

I'm using ReadFile with overlapped I/O like so:

```
while (continueReading)
{
    BOOL bSuccess = ReadFile(deviceHandle, pReadBuf, length, 
                             &bytesRead, readOverlappedPtr);
    waitVal = WaitForMultipleObjects(
                (sizeof(eventsToWaitFor)/sizeof(eventsToWaitFor[0])), 
                eventsToWaitFor, FALSE, INFINITE);
    if (waitVal == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
       // do stuff
    } else if (waitVal == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1) {
       // do stuff
    } else if (waitVal == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2) {
       // complete the read
       bSuccess = GetOverlappedResult(deviceHandle, &readOverlapped, 
                                      &bytesRead, FALSE);
       if (!bSuccess) {
          errorCode = GetLastError();
          printf("ReadFile error=%d\n", errorCode);
       }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ReadFile` is getting called more times than `GetOverlappedResult`.  Causing the process to run out of resources for dealing with all the outstanding reads.

Additionally, we should check the result of `ReadFile` and ensure the result is `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, if it isn't and `ReadFile` returned `FALSE` then there is another problem.

Ensure that `GetOverlappedResult` is called once for each successful call to `ReadFile`.  Like so:

```
BOOL bPerformRead = TRUE;
while (continueReading) 
{ 
    BOOL bSuccess = TRUE;
    // only perform the read if the last one has finished
    if (bPerformRead) {
       bSuccess = ReadFile(deviceHandle, pReadBuf, length,
                           &bytesRead, readOverlappedPtr);
       if (!bSuccess) {
          errorCode = GetLastError();
          if (errorCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
             printf("ReadFile error=%d\n", errorCode); 
             return;
          }
       } else {
          // read completed right away
          continue;
       }
       // we can't perform another read until this one finishes
       bPerformRead = FALSE;
    }
    waitVal = WaitForMultipleObjects( 
                (sizeof(eventsToWaitFor)/sizeof(eventsToWaitFor[0])),  
                eventsToWaitFor, FALSE, INFINITE); 
    if (waitVal == WAIT_OBJECT_0) { 
       // do stuff 
    } else if (waitVal == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1) { 
       // do stuff 
    } else if (waitVal == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2) { 
       // complete the read 
       bSuccess = GetOverlappedResult(deviceHandle, &readOverlapped,  
                                      &bytesRead, FALSE); 
       // the read is finished, we can read again
       bPerformRead = TRUE;
       if (!bSuccess) { 
          errorCode = GetLastError(); 
          printf("GetOverlappedResult from ReadFile error=%d\n", errorCode); 
       } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Closer.  But actually verifying that ReadFile returns FALSE and GetLastError() returns ERROR_IO_PENDING is *very* important.  Reading files often completes immediately when the data comes out of the file system cache.